# how to get around The '--' operator works only on variables or on properties

Tags: mysql, windows, powershell, escaping

I'm following the [instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.0/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html) from the mysql site on resetting the mysql server's password on a windows machine..

copying the command verbatim:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt.exe"
     --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini"
     --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

gives me this error (abbreviated):

```
Unexpected token 'defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySql\Mysql Server 5.0\my.ini"' 
in expression or statement.

The '--' operator works only on variables or on properties.

+ CategoryInfo          :ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :UnexpectedToken
```

I looked around and found [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ef93f6e-28c3-4077-b914-1d74be19837a/invokeexpression-vs-?forum=ITCG) suggestion:

> Try this:
>
> $cmd= {cmd /c 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\bin\pg_dump.exe
>   "--encoding=UTF8 --verbose --create --username=postgres --
>   file=C:\db\Wednesday.pg DB"'}
>
> &$cmd
>
> -- is the Powershell decrement operator.  To make it "mundate", it needs to be enclosed in single quotes to suppress parsing it as an
>   operator.  You could also escape all the hyphens with backticks, but
>   that's going to get really ugly.

I tried following that format.. ie

```
$cmd = {cmd /c 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt.exe
     "--defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini
     --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt"'}
&$cmd
```

but then i got this error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognised as an internal or external command
```

I also tried doing the back tick escaping:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt.exe"
     `-`-defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini"
     `-`-init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

but also got an error (abbreviated):

```
unexpected token '`-`-defaults-file.. ' in expression or statement
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The double dash for stopping parameter-processing is a sad choice for Powershell indeed.
I tried to get it working through Invoke-Command, but the below example worked best

```
&"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt.exe" '--defaults-file=""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini""' '--init-file="C:\mysql-init.txt"'
```

The executable between double quotes.

And the every parameter between single quotes, with the parameter value between double quotes (or double-double quotes to make the spaces in a path work)

Comment: this error occurred cause we were trying half of the expression in quotes and half like a regular one, putting both in single quotes actually worked for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

try the powershell V3 escape sequence `--%`

```
PS > echoargs --% --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini"

Arg 0 is <--defaults-file=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini>

Command line:
"C:\Windows\EchoArgs.exe"  --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your command should be:

```
 $cmd = {cmd /c '"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt.exe"
 --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini"
 --init-file="C:\\mysql-init.txt"'}
```

you are missing the double quotes

Comment: same error: `C:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: did you run my edited answer? this indicates that, your path does not quoted properly....

Comment: run this: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt.exe" --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini" --init-file="C:\\mysql-init.txt"